# Pandas concat dataframe given an index location

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with a multindex, and a row vector whose values I want to join to dataframe. The columns don't exist on the first dataframe in advance. For example:

```
# First dataframe, lots of rows, index on (city, animal, zoo)
city       animal   zoo
boston     pig      bns
new york   tiger    nycz
[...]

# Second dataframe, one row, non-label index 
    apple  banana   ...  grape
0   5      10       ...  37
```

I *know* the index I want to add my second dataframe to (but not the row number): `index = (boston, big, bns)`. So I tried doing:

```
first_dataframe[index, second_dataframe.columns] = second_dataframe
```

But I get a `KeyError` since the columns in the `second_dataframe` don't yet exist in the first one. I thought `merge` or `join` might be correct, but they require shared indices. `concat` looks the most correct, but I don't know how to specify `which` row in the first dataframe should get my second one.

My desired output is:

```
city       animal   zoo   apple  banana   ...  grape
boston     pig      bns   0   5      10   ...  37
new york   tiger    nycz  NaN NaN    NaN  ...  NaN
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the columns in df1 firstly , then assign the df2 value by `.values` with `loc`

```
index = ('boston', 'pig', 'bns')
df1=df1.assign(**dict(zip(df2.columns,[np.nan]*df2.shape[1])))
df1.loc[index,df2.columns]=df2.values
df1
                     apple  banana  grape
city    animal zoo                       
boston  pig    bns     5.0    10.0   37.0
newyork tiger  nycz    NaN     NaN    NaN
LOL     L      L       NaN     NaN    NaN
LOL1    L1     L1      NaN     NaN    NaN
```